# django - Sharing data between apps

Tags: django, django-models

I have just started playing around with django. I can foresee one app generating data that another could use (bad example: a geomatics app crunching complex data to generate simple location data to pass to another app that uses the data to decide some sort of business logic). Having never done any web programming with frameworks, my first thought was ....globals... But thats obviously not a "good thing"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a key to the client (either via a cookie or in the session) that can be used to retrieve the information from a datastore when needed.

Comment: what if the data transaction is independent of the user (ie not happening due to anything on the client side).

Comment: Then why does it need to be shared like that? Just call a function in the other app.

Comment: @michael: I think you're overthinking it. Everything is in the same environment, so you can call any Python code in your app from any other app. Signals are for notifications about *events*. Depending on your situation, you might indeed find them useful. But the general case you ask about doesn't need them.

Comment: So i only need to concern myself with design issues (eg: not coupling apps) then, and not issues of framework/language (eg: scope)?